# Inspecting Request Query With WebApi2 Controller and DataTables

Tags: asp.net-web-api, datatables, asp.net-web-api2

I have implemented a WebApi2 Controller that I am using to return data to a jQuery DataTable.   I am getting an error on the parsing the query from the URI.   VS is throwing a Null Exception error because RequestUri.Query is null.

I have inspected the request in Fiddler and this is what is being sent to the controller from the DataTable code:

```
GET /api/GetMyStuff?sEcho=1&...
```

Here is the Controller:

```
 [Route(Name ="GetMyStuff")]
        public SysDataTablePager Get()
        {
            NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);
            string sEcho = nvc["sEcho"].ToString();
            int iDisplayStart = Convert.ToInt32(nvc["iDisplayStart"]);
            ...LINQ QUERIES HERE
            var MyStuffPaged = new SysDataTablePager();


           MyStuffPaged.iTotalRecords = count;
           MyStuffPaged.iTotalDisplayRecords = count;
           MyStuffPaged.aaData = materials.ToList();

        return MyStuffPaged ;
      }
```

My JS code is as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('table.grid').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "api/GetMyStuff",
        "sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [
                    { "sName": "Name",
                        "bSearchable": false,
                        "bSortable": false,
                        "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                            return '<a href=\"Details/' + 
                            oObj.aData[0] + '\">View</a>';
                        }
                    },
                    { "sName": "Description" }

    ]
    });
});
```

For completeness here is my return model

```
public class SysDataTablePager
{
    public string sEcho { get; set; }
    public int iTotalRecords { get; set; }
    public int iTotalDisplayRecords { get; set; }
    public List<StuffModel> aaData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: why don't you use regular action parameters instead of trying to parse the requestUri yourself?

Comment: What would that look like?  Just add a param in the signature?  Sorry, I am relatively new to this and sometimes don't see how things fit together.

Comment: Get([FromBody])  like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing the above comment about using the MVC framework to parse your query for you:

```
    [Route(Name ="GetMyStuff")]
    public SysDataTablePager Get(string sEcho, int iDisplayStart)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Ahhh, I think I understand.  Since it's being sent with the request, I should just tell the method to grab it and set it?